# GitHub - Get the author (not the committer) of an old commit

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I am trying to get the author on GitHub (and not only the committer) of an old commit +90 days.
To say differently, an old commit was committed when naming my account differently (committer = ABC for example). Now I must proof that my email is the one used to do that old commit.

Is there anyway to do so? when using the api github events, I am not able to go further than 90 days.

Comment: Can you clone the repository?  Do you know the ID of the commit in question?

Comment: is that commit still part of the repository's history ? or was it rewritten/edited, and the original commit is now unreachable ?

Comment: @bk2204 yes of course I know my commit ID.

Comment: @LeGEC no the history has not been edited at all and I know my commit ID.
It is still reachable of course but it is indicating that its author is ABC for example (the name chosen and used when I did the commit) and I want to prove that my email (me) is the one who did it.

Comment: Using the API GitHub events, I am only able only to verify for a commit within 90 days that ABC is me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GitHub API to fetch it from the API response for that commit using the Git Contents API.  For example, to get the data from the initial commit for Git:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/commits/e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290
{
  "sha": "e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290",
  "node_id": "MDY6Q29tbWl0MzY1MDI6ZTgzYzUxNjMzMTZmODliZmJkZTdkOWFiMjNjYTJlMjU2MDRhZjI5MA==",
  "commit": {
    "author": {
      "name": "Linus Torvalds",
      "email": "torvalds@ppc970.osdl.org",
      "date": "2005-04-07T22:13:13Z"
    },
    "committer": {
      "name": "Linus Torvalds",
      "email": "torvalds@ppc970.osdl.org",
      "date": "2005-04-07T22:13:13Z"
    },
    ...
  },
...
}
```

The data is in the `author` object.